# Splitting a txt file into indiviudal words andwriting them to a new txt file

Tags: python, object

I wanted to take a txt file that is formatted as such:

```
apple banana peach pear
```

(item then space then next item) and then print it so that it prints as:

```
apple
banana
peach
pear
```

At the same time, it has to write to the file called output.txt in the same manner (each word on a new line). My code so far as is follows and I would appreciate it if only changes would be made to it and not a new code itself.

```
def task_2():

   in_file = open("input.txt", "r")
   out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
   line = in_file.line()
   words = line.strip()
   for word in words:
       print(f'word\n')
       out_file.write(word)
   in_file.close()
   out_file.close()
```

Comment: Does `input.txt` only ever contain a single line of words?

Comment: `data = in_file.read().replace(' ', '\n'); print(data);  fileout.write(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of small mistakes:

```
def task_2():
    in_file = open("input.txt", "r")  # this is better with a context manager
    out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    line = in_file.line()  # .line() does not exist, you wanted .readline()
    words = line.strip()  # you want .split() here
    for word in words:
        print(f'word\n')  # you use an f-string, but forgot the {}
        out_file.write(word)
    in_file.close()  # with a context manager, these are not needed
    out_file.close()
```

So:

```
def task_2():
    with open("input.txt", "r") as in_file:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
            line = in_file.readline()
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                print(f'{word}')  # also, print automatically writes a newline
                out_file.write(f'{word}\n')  # but .write() doesn't


task_2()  # let's also call the function
```

However, you can combine those two context manager `with` lines into a single one and save a few needless variables as well:

```
def task_2():
    with open("input.txt", "r") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for word in in_file.readline().split():
            print(f'{word}')
            out_file.write(f'{word}\n')


task_2()
```